# What is the point of JObject's CreateWriter if using the writer just throws ArgumentException?

Tags: json.net

I have a "legacy" method that takes a JsonWriter and dumps a bunch of json..   Out of this, I want a JObject instance, so I tried the following:

```
JObject myObj = new JObject();
using (var writer = myObj.CreateWriter())
{
    TheLegacyMethod(writer);
}
// TODO:  Do stuff with the nicely initialized JObject instance
```

The issue is that the first time "TheLegacyMethod" attempts to actually use the writer to do a:

```
writer.WriteStartObject();
```

I get an ArgumentException complaining that a JObject can't be added to a JObject.

I've used a smelly workaround, writing the Json to a StringBuilder first, then doing a JObject.Parse() on the result...  but I would like to avoid this intermediate.

What is the point of JObject.CreateWriter() if you can't use it?   Am I missing something?  (I'm hoping I am).

Thanks,

Tyler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing values to an object the property name must be written before the value.

Comment: Ah hah!  The legacy method was writing the outer "{ }", wrapping everything in a complete (unnamed) object...  but when I'm already starting with a JObject instance, this is redundant and violates Json  (i.e. it'd end up being like this "{ { "prop" : value, "prop" : value } }").